# Angular-6 validation

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Am trying to do a form validation in angular 6

Html code

```
<form [formGroup]="providerForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="provider.name"
                    name="name" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required"> Name is required</div>
                        </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
    export class ProviderserviceComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
         submitted = false;
        provider: Provider = new Provider();
        providerForm: FormGroup;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.providerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                name: ['', Validators.required]
            });

        }
        get f() { return this.providerForm.controls; }
        onClickSubmit(data) {
            this.submitted = true;

        }
```

In app.modeule.ts,component.ts file i added the following modules
FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators,
 when i debug on html file its showing error.

[image]

Comment: the `provider` is not defined anywhere and you are trying to use `provider.name` in the [(ngModel)].

Comment: provider defined inside component

Comment: Code looks ok.. If you are still getting the error, please create a minimal reproduction using stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="provider.name"`  ngmodel isn't required for reactive forms.  the matching is done on the `formControlName`.  passing data to the form is done through `setValue` / `patchValue`.  please check the documentation for a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML File**

```
<form [formGroup]="providerForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit()">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" required (ngModel)]="provider.fname" placeholder="Name" formControlName="fname" #fname>

     <div *ngIf="submitted && f.fname.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.fname.errors.required"> Name is required</div>
      </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class ProviderserviceComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
         submitted = false;
        provider: Provider = new Provider();
        providerForm: FormGroup;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.providerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                fname: ['', Validators.required]
            });

        }
        get f() { return this.providerForm.controls; }
        onClickSubmit(data) {
            this.submitted = true;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `FormBuilder` and `ngModel`, because both of them are using same work

For example try removing

```
this.providerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       name: ['', Validators.required]
});
```